# How to sync data between two table in two different database

Tags: c#, synchronization

Suppose I have two sql server databases and having same schema. I want to synchronize data between two table of that two databases.

How could I do this? Is there any free open source good library which help me to develop this sort of apps or is there any already free dotnet apps which do the task?

Answer (score 1):

If it is Sql Server that you are using you also have the option of using Sql Server Replication.

Comment: i know that it is possible with replication but i want to develop a frontend tool who does the job. so i need ur advice that how develop this type of frontend tool with c#. is there any library available who does the job? thanks

Comment: Thomas, unless you have a real reason to do this I would strongly recommend the use of Sql Server Replication. It already provides a front end tool to manage and follow the replication statuses and also logging and error handling.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [SQL Server Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx). It is possible to replicate only parts of the database or the database as a whole.

Comment: i know that it is possible with replication but i want to develop a frontend tool who does the job. so i need ur advice that how develop this type of frontend tool with c#. is there any library available who does the job? thanks

Comment: If it will be driven through a tool and the process will be manually initiated, you can write your own SQL queries to do this, by selecting data from both tables in pages in some order and comparing them and inserting as necessary. I am not aware of such a tool that does this. SQL Replication is more for instant/near instant replication of all the data.

Answer (score 0):

Do they need to be synchronized 24/7 or is overnight Synchronization acceptable?